# Turn.js like flipbook for ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mobile, ionic2

I've searced all around the internet for a flipbook plugin for ionic 2 but failed to find one. I later tried to include javascript flipbook plugins as external libraries but failed everytime. Is there any npm flipbook packages out there? If there are no, how can I include a javascript plugin in my ionic 2 projects?

Answer (score 3):

"*Is there any npm flipbook packages out there?*"
You can try this repository: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-turnjs

"*how can I include a javascript plugin in my ionic 2 projects?*"

I choose to implement TurnJS importing as external library. You can clone a working version using Ionic 3 here: https://github.com/diegonobre/ionic-turnjs

If you want to implement your own version, follow below instructions:

## Create ionic project usign Ionic CLI

```
ionic start ionic-turnjs blank
```

## Add jQuery and TurnJS

- Copy jQuery and TurnJS libs to your `src/assets` folder
- Edit your `src/index.html` to add the above code before the `</head>` tag

## Replace `home.ts` with the above code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public platform: Platform
    ) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        $("#flipbook").turn({
            width: '100%',
            height: this.platform.height() - 50,
            display: 'single',
            autoCenter: true
        });
    }
}
```

## Create your TurnJS view

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="flipbook">
        <div class="cover"> Turn.js </div>
        <div class="page"> Page 1 </div>
        <div class="page"> Page 2 </div>
        <div class="page"> Page 3 </div>
        <div class="page"> Page 4 </div>
        <div class="cover"> The end </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

## Add CSS to `home.scss`

```
page-home {
    .cover {
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    .page {
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color: white;
        border: solid 1px gray;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your solution! Worked for me. I load the flipbook after the platform is ready
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => this.ionViewDidLoad());
}